# How to rotate an image overlay in ffmpeg around the image center?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to scale, rotate and overlay an image on a video. I'm able to rotate the image by the desired angle but the overlay ends up being moved both vertically and horizontally from the expected position.

The commands I've tried and their corresponding outputs are shown below. Command 1 gives the expected output, 2 and 3 do not.

**How can I modify my commands in general, to rotate the overlay image around the image center, to get the expected output?**

[image: Command 1]

> ffmpeg -i graphpaper.mp4 -i arrow.png -y -filter_complex [1:v]scale=w=364:h=370[overlay0];[overlay0]rotate=a=0:c=none:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=419:y=168[output0] -map [output0] sample-overlay-on-graph-paper.mp4

[image: Command 2]

> ffmpeg -i graphpaper.mp4 -i arrow.png -y -filter_complex [1:v]scale=w=364:h=370[overlay0];[overlay0]rotate=a=0.8017360589297406:c=none:ow=rotw(0.8017360589297406):oh=roth(0.8017360589297406)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=419:y=168[output0] -map [output0] sample-overlay-on-graph-paper.mp4

[image: Command 3]

> ffmpeg -i graphpaper.mp4 -i arrow.png -y -filter_complex [1:v]scale=w=364:h=370[overlay0];[overlay0]rotate=a=5.493783719179012:c=none:ow=rotw(5.493783719179012):oh=roth(5.493783719179012)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=419:y=168[output0] -map [output0] sample-overlay-on-graph-paper.mp4

Links to input files:

- graphpaper.mp4 https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhfa8.jpg
- arrow.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8QvZ.jpg

Comment: options ow and oh changes size of pic. remove em and increase pad of pic or use ow oh from doc `..:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow` everywhere

Comment: 'ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow' gave the same result as the problematic ones above. Can you elaborate on the increase the pad of picture suggestion?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i arrow.png -vf "pad='hypot(iw,ih)':ow:-1:-1:black@0" -frames 1 arrow_pad.png` or `[1:v]pad=...,scale...`

Comment: I tried your command, it's an improvement over commands 2 and 3, but it still does not give the exact expected result.

Comment: `ffmpeg -t 3 -i in.mp4 -loop 1 -t 3 -i arrow.png -filter_complex "
[1:v]scale=364:370,split[v1][v2];
[v1]rotate=a=0:c=none:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[r1];
[v2]rotate=a=PI/4:c=none:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[r2];
[0:v][r1]overlay=209:0[r1];
[r1][r2]overlay=209:0
"  out.mp4` looks good

Comment: Thanks for being persistent with providing solutions. I tried your command. This command doesn't give me the expected result because the ow and oh of the reference and rotated images are similar. The problem I'm trying to solve is where the ow and oh of reference and rotated images are not identical, so an adjustment needs to be made to the overlay x & y of the rotated image. [1/2]

Comment: I *think* the final solution would look like this, in pseudocode: ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i arrow.png -y -filter_complex [1:v]scale=w=364:h=370[overlay0];[overlay0]rotate=a=radians:c=none:ow=rotw(radians):oh=roth(radians)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=419-x_adjustment:y=168-y_adjustment[output0] -map [output0] sample-overlay-on-graph-paper.mp4 . The x_adjustment would be (ow-iw) of the rotated image and y_adjustment would be (oh-ih) of the rotated image.  Question is how to implement this math in the command. Any ideas?[2/2]

Comment: Update to my previous comment: The correct x_adjustment=(ow-iw)/2 and y_adjustment=(oh-ih)/2 as the rotation is around image center.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов if you'd like to post a command with the adjustments as answer, I'll mark it correct. Your commands and comment that rotw changes size led me to the right approach.

Comment: try this. without calculating ow oh: `ffmpeg -t 3 -i "in" -loop 1 -t 3 -i arrow.png -filter_complex "
[1:v]pad='hypot(iw,ih)':ow:-1:-1:color=black@0, scale=400:400,split[v1][v2];
[v1]rotate=a=0:c=none[r1];
[v2]rotate=a=PI/4:c=none[r2];
[0:v][r1]overlay=300-w/2:200-h/2[r1];
[r1][r2]overlay=300-w/2:200-h/2
" out.mp4` where 300 and 200 in overlay are coordinates of center of arrow.png

Comment: Thanks, looks good. If you post this as answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create graphpaper

```
ffmpeg -lavfi "
color=white:1280x720:d=5,
drawgrid=0:0:25:25:0x7fffff,
drawgrid=0:0:100:100:0x00ffff
" -c:v ffv1 -g 1 "graphpaper.mkv"
```

create arrow.png

```
ffmpeg -lavfi "
color=green:400x400,format=argb,
geq=r=0:a='
 if(lt(Y,H/2-10)
,if(lt(X,W/2),if(between(X,W/2-Y,W/2+14-Y),255),if(between(X,W/2-14+Y,W/2+Y),255))
,if(lt(Y,H/2)
,if(lt(X,W/2),if(between(X,W/2-Y,W/2-90),255),if(between(X,W/2+90,W/2+Y),255))
,if(lt(Y,H-10)
,if(between(X,100,110)+between(X,W-110,W-100),255)
,if(between(X,100,W-100),255))))'
" -frames 1 "arrow.png"
```

overlay 2 times with different angles

```
ffmpeg -i graphpaper.mkv -i arrow.png -filter_complex "
[1:v]pad='hypot(iw,ih)':ow:-1:-1:color=black@0,split[v1][v2];
[v1]rotate=0:c=none[r1];
[v2]rotate=PI/4:c=none[r2];
[0:v][r1]overlay=300-w/2:200-h/2[r1];
[r1][r2]overlay=300-w/2:200-h/2
" out.mp4
```

300 and 200 are position of the center of rotation of the image

Comment: Amazing answer. Solves my problem and does it with a flourish.

Answer (score 0):

[Source: GitHub](https://github.com/ThreadsStyling/video-renderer/blob/master/docs/ffmpeg-examples.md)

Rotate by 1rad (around center-center origin).

```
./src/node/__tests__/bin/ffmpeg -y \
  -i assets/image.jpg  \
  -i assets/servers.png  \
  -filter_complex "[1] rotate=angle=1[rotated];[0][rotated] overlay=0:0" \
  output.jpg
```